# How to increase the code coverage of express based node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

I am working on writing unit test cases for REST APIs developed using node.js. I am using tape for writing unit tests. I came across istanbul npm which can actually tracks the lines of code and branches  tested by Unit tests and generates a nice report at the end of it which can be published( nowhere to hide :) ).

The istanbul report clearly reflects that error conditions(branches) that i put for handling errors particularly of database in node.js code are not getting hit at the time of execution of unit test cases.

Since the APIs are hosted on express, i am not sure that how can i "generate" database related errors (like connection refused) once the server is up so that i can improve upon the "code-coverage" while execution of unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Digging around on this same question and I found that they've added support in Istanbul for commenting sections that should be ignored for coverage. More here: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/ignoring-code-for-coverage.md